# Using git on generated code with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, git, code-generation

I have a problem with Git ignoring automatic changes my server does in the local repo. I have a generator, which generates a code and stores it in a folder called "generated/". I am using NodeJS for this and the procedure of writing files is done by:

```
fs.WriteFileSync();
```

According to the documentation this function:

> synchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists. data can be a string or a buffer.

The "generated/" folder has a git repo inside and at the end of each code generation it automatically calls:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

This is suppose to push the generated code to a remote repository. But it does not. It is always one generation behind for some reason. If I generate a code in generation #1 and push it, no changes are pushed to the repo. If I generate again in generation #2, the changes from generation #1 are pushed to the repo. It is always one generation behind.

My guess is that it is because the function I use replaces the files and Git does not know about it at first to only the old changes are pushed. Once I call another generation, Git finally knows that there are some changes done in the first code generation and pushes that one.

I hope my description is proper. Does anyone knows how to fix it? I think I need to let Git know that the files were replaced but I do not know how.

Any help please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could find all the untracked files and add them,

```
for i in `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`
do
git add $i
done
```

or just the changed files

```
for i in `git diff --name-only`
do
git add $i
done
```

the continue with your commit and push.

Comment: The thing is that the files are basically the same. Same name, just different content due to the generation. Do you think this would work?

Comment: I will try. I need to figure out how to actually call one of those two commands you wrote with the git binder I am using for Node.

Comment: The version with `git diff --name-only` works! Awesome.